# Python: File operation problems in python execution

Tags: python

I am trying to execute a python file located in some folder named : folder1

for this I am using :

**~$ python /folder1/a.py** (doesn't work)

When i go to that folder and then execute everything works fine:

**~/folder1$ python a.py**   (works)

I think I am using a file write operation in code written in file a.py because of which first way of execution is not working.
Please give some suggestions to fix this.

Comment: can you please share the error message you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path on the first try: `/folder1/a.py` starts searching from root directory (`/`), that's why it doesn't find the script. It would be correctly done like this:

```
~$ python folder1/a.py
```

Notice how I removed the beginning `/` character. Take a look at man [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) to see how UNIX/Linux OS look up commands and files.

Comment: Hi Paulo, thanks for quick response.. but this is not the problem i am facing. actually the problem is if i work with a file which doesn't have file write operation in there it works from any directory. but when I use file write operation it works only from the directory where the python code file is kept.

Comment: @RajanRai That's kind of weird, can you add more information to the question? Like the error messages, file permissions and the exact execution command?

Answer (score 0):

The File was always going to home folder..
I grabbed the absolute path and it worked perfectly for me..

and thanks to Paulo's hint about permissions of file.